# Changing LaTeX Math Font on Webpage

Tags: fonts

I'm very new to the world of LaTeX and have a few of what I would imagine will be very basic questions regarding LaTeX display fonts. On my site, the default LaTeX display font is set to a font different than that of the HTML text on the site (i.e. Times New Roman). Here is a screenshot of section with regular paragraph text and LaTeX:

Write out the equations for the areas of triangles and rectangles.

> $$A_{triangle}= \frac{1}{2} bh$$

> $$A_{rectangle}= bh$$

[image: Text/LaTeX comparison]

As you can see, this is aesthetically undesirable. I would much rather have the LaTeX be the same font and size as the ordinary paragraph text. I've looked at some forums and tried some of the solutions presented but nothing seems to give me an overall fix.

I have two questions:
1. Is there a way to change my global LaTeX display settings to match the font of my HTML text?
2. Is there a way to change LaTeX display settings in-line to match fonts of neighboring HTML paragraphs?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.